# Does GAE Image service auto shrink my uploaded images?

Tags: google-app-engine

I use GAE ImageService to get a permanent link of my uploaded pictures:

```
    ServingUrlOptions originOption = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey);
    String imageUrl= imagesService.getServingUrl(originOption);
```

But when i open the imageUrl from browser, the size is shrank, for example the origin size is 1366 x 642, but when i open it in browser it is 512 × 241.

How can i get the original image i uploaded with a permanent link( which will be used in background image url in css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getServingUrl()` gives you a URL for serving a thumbnail of your original image. That's how it's [documented](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/#Java_Transforming_images_from_the_Blobstore) to work. Check the docs, and look at the options for appending to the URL to get different sizes. Appending `=s0` will get you a full-sized image. (The effect of zero is under-documented. I'll see about getting that fixed.)